# Qgis python to apply polygon Symbology

Tags: pyqgis, symbology

I have polygon featureclass. which is shown in map as
[image: Original symbolgy]

I want to "outline xpattern" symbology
[image: Outline xpattern from symblogy]

I am not able to do it programmatically by python.

Few of my attempts are:
Attempt1:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("New_Shapefile")[0] # replace "polygon_layer_name" with the actual name of your polygon layer

symbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'outline_style': 'no', 'outline_width': '0.26', 'outline_color': '0,0,0,255', 'pattern': '20'})

renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol)

layer.setRenderer(renderer)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Attempt 2:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon_layer_name")[0] # replace "polygon_layer_name" with the actual name of your polygon layer

fill_symbol = QgsFillSymbol.createSimple({'color': '247,247,247,255'})

layer_1 = QgsFillSymbolLayer(fill_symbol)
layer_2 = QgsFillSymbolLayer(fill_symbol)
layer_3 = QgsFillSymbolLayer(fill_symbol)

symbol = QgsFillSymbol([layer_1, layer_2, layer_3])

renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(symbol)

layer.setRenderer(renderer)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were close, you just needed `QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayer` for the outline points.

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon_layer_name")[0] # replace "polygon_layer_name" with the actual name of your polygon layer

red = QColor(255,0,0)
green = QColor(0,255,0)
whiteish = QColor(247,247,247)

fill = QgsSimpleFillSymbolLayer()
fill.setColor(whiteish)

marker_r = QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayer(interval=9)
marker_r.setColor(red)
marker_r.setOffsetAlongLine(4.5)

marker_g = QgsMarkerLineSymbolLayer(interval=9)
marker_g.setColor(green)

fill_symbol = QgsFillSymbol([fill, marker_r, marker_g])
renderer = QgsSingleSymbolRenderer(fill_symbol)

layer.setRenderer(renderer)

layer.triggerRepaint()
```

UPDATE: you can also use the predefined style like this:

```py
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName("polygon_layer_name")[0] # replace "polygon_layer_name" with the actual name of your polygon layer

symbol = QgsStyle.defaultStyle().symbol("outline xpattern")
layer.renderer().setSymbol(symbol)
layer.triggerRepaint()
```

Comment: I haven't managed to find if/where the "outline xpattern" symbology is defined and whether or not it is directly accessible from pyqgis, it should probably be. So here is a close enough copy of the symbology might be missing a couple parameter not sure

Comment: Nevermind I found it

Comment: Thanks..this worked!